# Difference Between index.php?id=1 and index.php/id/1

Tags: laravel, rest, url, nginx, laravel-routing

1. If I want to create RESTful APIs, which one should I choose?
2. How do the URLs as index.php/id/1 work? I think it's a file path, not a URL.
3. If I want to get an image as abc.com/img/1.png, it may have conflicts with abc.com/img/{param}. How do I solve?

BTW, I use Laravel now.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Laravel use item/{id} convention. see this https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in route model binding

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-model-binding

This allows you to get the model with the id that is passed into the route

So for example a route like this:

```
Route::get('users/{user}', 'UsersController@getUser');
```

Will allow you to do this in you method:

```
use App\User

public function getUser(User $user) {

    return $user;

}
```

This means that you get the full record for the id that is in the route.

So your Questions:

1: I would use this for sending model id's
2: the variables in the route are passed in that order to the method allowing you to get access to them.
3: You will need to be careful with your routes as you can have conflicts. having said that Laravel does not use a traditional directory structure for storage. I believe that if you have a folder stucture of /public/img and that folder contains an img named 1.png it will get the image but I have not tested this.